# cursor.moveToFirst() returning false even though data is present in table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a table named as 'products3' which has columns 'id','type','width','length','thickness','quantity'..(in order) and other than 'type' all other columns are 'int' 
I wish to select quantity and return it by filtering data on other columns.
Cursor in method 'findproduct' returns false or NULL in the if condition even though the data is present in the table I have browsed the table using DB browser for SQLite   !! please help

```
    public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    int s;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB3.db";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products3";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    public static final String COLUMN_WIDTH = "width";
    public static final String COLUMN_LENGTH = "length";
    public static final String COLUMN_THICK = "thick";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,
                       SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + COLUMN_TYPE
                + " TEXT," + COLUMN_WIDTH + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_LENGTH + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_THICK + " INTEGER,"
                + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                          int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addProduct(String type,int width,int length,int thick,int quant) {


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TYPE,type);
        values.put(COLUMN_WIDTH,width);
        values.put(COLUMN_LENGTH,length);
        values.put(COLUMN_THICK,thick);
        values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY,quant);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public int findProduct(String type,int width,int length,int thick) {

        String query = "SELECT quantity FROM products3 WHERE type='" + type +"' AND width=" + width + " AND length=" +
                length+" AND thick=" + thick + ";";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();

           s=cursor.getInt(0);

            cursor.close();
            return s;
        }
        db.close();
        return 0;
       }

    public boolean deleteProduct(String type,int width,int length,int thick) {



        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM products3 WHERE type='" + type +"' and width=" + width + " and length=" +
                length+" and thick=" + thick );
        db.close();
           }
}
```

Comment: add the error log.

Comment: stack trace please

Comment: @Suhail Jain try this  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: What is your first column? Is it a String : cursor.getString(0)

Comment: @Chol no it is not

Comment: @RohitArya my logcat shows too much output to display

Comment: @JagjitSingh didn't work :(

Comment: Your cursor has only one column but you're trying to get the value from the sixth one at index 5. That won't work and is one crash reason here. But there might be other problems too, and you didn't specify your problem really.

Comment: Start your app. Clear your logcat window, just beforea call to this method is made. Scroll your logcat window. Somewhere it must be displaying you the error.

Comment: As others said, you have only one column in the cursor, and it will be easier to post the logcat where crash happens

Comment: all I can see in my logcat is this infinite times.. it doesnot stop
03-21 20:38:33.625 952-971/? E/SensorManager: handleEvent called
03-21 20:38:33.625 952-971/? E/SensorManager: dispatchSensorEvent to java level

Comment: @laalto I tried passing 0 as argument to the getInt() method .. but it still crashes

Comment: @Suhail Jain Post your whole code where creating table so i can check for data types and all

Comment: @JagjitSingh done.

Comment: I went to the doctor and told him it hurts when I lift my arm.  He told me not to lift my arm.  To give similar advice, don't call the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble debugging your SQL query, Android provides a handy method [DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString%28android.database.Cursor%29) that formats the entire Cursor into a String. You can then output the dump to LogCat and see the result of your query.